# Microsoft Graph - SharePoint Document Upload using Chunk Upload loses HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

We are using a MVC CRM that uses OWIN and integrates to SharePoint using Microsoft Graph rest API (MSAL), and we are trying to upload files to a SharePoint site document library.

Here's the code

```
 private const int MAX_CHUNK_SIZE = 25 * 320 * 1024;
public async static Task<bool> UploadFile(string siteName, string folderId, string filename, Stream memoryStream)
        {
            try
            { 
            var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();
            var uploadSession = await CreateUploadSession(siteName, folderId, filename);
            var provider = new ChunkedUploadProvider(uploadSession, graphClient, memoryStream, MAX_CHUNK_SIZE );



            var chunkRequests = provider.GetUploadChunkRequests();
            var readBuffer = new byte[MAX_CHUNK_SIZE];
            var trackedExceptions = new List<Exception>();
            DriveItem itemResult = null;


            foreach (var request in chunkRequests)
            {

                var result = await provider.GetChunkRequestResponseAsync(request, readBuffer, trackedExceptions);

                if (result.UploadSucceeded)
                {

                    return true;
                }
            }

            if (itemResult == null)
            {
                return false;

            }

            return false;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

However, when it goes to GetChunkRequestResponseAsync method, it goes to our GraphHelper to check the authenticated client that has the SessionTokenStore, but the HttpContext is lost (null), and throws an Object reference not set to an instance of an object

> Code: generalException
>   Message: An error occurred sending the request.
>      at HomeImprover.Web.TokenStorage.SessionTokenStore.GetUsersUniqueId() in C:\Visual Studio Projects\HITS\HomeImprover.Web\TokenStorage\SessionTokenStore.cs:line 112
>      at HomeImprover.Web.TokenStorage.SessionTokenStore..ctor(ITokenCache tokenCache, HttpContext context) in C:\Visual Studio Projects\HITS\HomeImprover.Web\TokenStorage\SessionTokenStore.cs:line 36
>      at HomeImprover.Web.Services.Graph.GraphHelper.<>c.<b__4_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Visual Studio Projects\HITS\HomeImprover.Web\Services\Graph\GraphHelper.cs:line 35
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Graph.AuthenticationHandler.d__16.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.d__19.MoveNext()

```
 private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
        {
            return new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                            .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
                            .Build();

                        var tokenStore = new SessionTokenStore(idClient.UserTokenCache,
                                HttpContext.Current);

                        var accounts = await idClient.GetAccountsAsync();

                        // By calling this here, the token can be refreshed
                        // if it's expired right before the Graph call is made
                        var scopes = graphScopes.Split(' ');
                        var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                            .ExecuteAsync();

                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                    }));
        }
 public SessionTokenStore(ITokenCache tokenCache, HttpContext context)
        {
            httpContext = context;

            if (tokenCache != null)
            {
                tokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
                tokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
            }

            var userId = GetUsersUniqueId();
            tokenCacheKey = $"{userId}_TokenCache";
            userCacheKey = $"{userId}_UserCache";
        }
private string GetUsersUniqueId()
        {
            return httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        }
```

We are not sure what we would be doing wrong as MS advises to always use Chunk Upload since it allows uploading  >4MB files, additionally, we followed the uploading example close to verbatim.

Lastly, we can see a temp file starting to get uploaded on the SharePoint site document alike ~tmp40_document.pdf, which adds a piece to the puzzle.

Any help will be appreciated.